# Convert fat controller to scope, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble setting up multi parameter scopes, where I don't know how many parameters will be supplied, I have posted below my "fat controller", and would like to know how to do it in a proper scope.... (or alternative I guess)

```
def browse
    conditions = {}
    if params[:category].present?
        conditions[:category] = params[:category]
    end
    if params[:make].present?
      conditions[:make] = params[:make]
    end
    @cars = Car.where(conditions)
end
```

This is the best way I can think of, of making sure that if only one of the two parameters are supplied then it handles it correctly. I feel the controller code above is fairly self explanatory but happy to provide more info. (there is additional logic that resides in each present? block, but I have removed it to make the code more legible)

Comment: For completeness, can you not show the whole code?

Comment: The reason I ask is because you can quite easily remove your presence checkers by using this first: `params.keep_if { |k,v| v.present? }`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use ARel for all it's worth. What I mean is, ARel provides chainability and that would work great here! Here's how I'd do this:

```
def browse
  arel_base = Car.all
  arel_base = arel_base.where(category: params[:category]) if params[:category].present?
  arel_base = arel_base.where(make: params[:make]) if params[:make].present?
  @cars = arel_base
end
```

I used `arel_base` simply because I find that I often want to keep a copy of the base arel around for other queries such as record counts, etc. So I can use it to do that from and @cars can be my end result for the index page (usually paginated). If you don't need any of this then just use `@cars` in place of `arel_base`.

The above is an improvement, but what I would actually do is take it one step further and define scopes for each of the `.where` conditions. So on the Car model, add scopes like:

```
scope :for_category, -> category { where(category: category) }
scope :for_make, -> make { where(make: make) }
```

Then you can simplify your controller a bit more while also reducing coupling:

```
def browse
  arel_base = Car.all
  arel_base = arel_base.for_category(params[:category]) if params[:category].present?
  arel_base = arel_base.for_category(params[:make]) if params[:make].present?
  @cars = arel_base
end
```

**UPDATE**

Using Rails 4 syntax for spawning a ActiveRecord::Relation on the Car model -- which is `.all` instead of `.scoped` as Rails < 4 used to use.

Comment: I saw the "Car.scope" example, but it's not in rails 4? or is that a arel gem thing?

Comment: Good point. I think Rails < 4.1 uses `scoped` and 4.1 uses `scope` (or `spawn`). Updated my answer to show `.scoped`.

Comment: Actually, it looks like Rails 4 deprecated using `.scoped` in favor of using `.all`. (And `.to_a` is meant to replace the old `.all` behavior, as I understand it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your current controller to this:

```
def browse
  filter = [:category, :make]
  params.slice(*filter).keep_if { |k,v| v.present? }
  @cars = Car.where(params)
end
```

I would suggest building a `filter` helper either within your ApplicationHelper or a custom module.

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def filter(model, params)
    params.keep_if { |k,v| v.present? }
    model.where(params)
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def browse
    @cars = filter(Car, params_to_filter)
  end

  private

  def params_to_filter
    params.slice(:category, :make)
  end
end
```

You could argue the `filter` helper belongs in the model layer. That's up to you. This is just a general idea to get you started. The point is, if your filtering code is already becoming complicated, reducing to scopes will only take you so far. Abstract the filtering where appropriate.

This can be especially helpful if you use a third party library that has complex filtering, such as DataTables.